# How to detect whether pdf is scanned document using Tika parser / Java

Tags: java, pdf, ocr, apache-tika

I am trying to extract text from pdf files. But in some of the cases pdf file are scanned copies of hard documents.

Is there a way i can find whether the given pdf is scanned copy of papers or normal pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Check if a PDF file is a scanned one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403789/check-if-a-pdf-file-is-a-scanned-one)?

Regardless - recent versions of Tika can optionally use [Tesseract to OCR](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/PDFParser%20%28Apache%20PDFBox%29) the images before attempting content extraction - if you are using this and want to know how the document was parsed by Tika you can inspect the metadata: the PDFParser adds `org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser` to the `X-Parsed-By` metadata key in addition to the usual `org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser`.

If you are trying to decide whether to run your own OCR processing before running Tika, you will likely need to pre-process the PDF (eg pdfimages / some other command line tool, or a PDFBox based solution) to determine whether it contains only full-page images (or smaller images that cover the page) with no text operators, and then possibly to try and classify them to see whether they need OCRing.