# PDFBox : Are there alternatives to getFontNames method to get the fonts used in a PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox

My project deals with scanned PDFs that I need to detect. Those can have many different "shapes". One of them (that is confidential) is an image with the stamp "copy" **typewritten** on top of it. Of course the stamp can be anything in any language.

Because of this typewritten stamp added on top, parsing the pdf file gives the contents "copy", so it cannot be simply detected as a scanned PDF. Consequently based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403789/check-if-a-pdf-file-is-a-scanned-one) I am first trying to find all the fonts embedded in the document with the following code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < pageLimit; ++i) {
        PDPage page = pdf.getPage(i);
        PDResources res = page.getResources();
        for (COSName c : res.getFontNames()){
            System.err.println("The font is " + c.getName());
        }
        // There is at least one font in this pdf
        if (res.getFontNames().iterator().hasNext()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Indeed I just need to know if there are fonts. However with that file (and perhaps other ones that I haven't tested yet) PDFBox returns nothing for the font names whereas Evince reports "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" and "TimesNewRomanPSMT" and even PDFBox shows :

> WARN  Using fallback font 'LiberationSerif-Bold' for 'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT'
>   WARN  Using fallback font 'LiberationSerif' for 'TimesNewRomanPSMT'

Yet how can I get to know for sure whether fonts are contained in the PDF or not when `getFontNames()` returns nothing ?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: the fonts can also be in a form XObject, a pattern or softmask. Most likely in the form xobject.

Comment: Considering that *parsing the pdf file gives the contents "copy"* I'm actually sure that it's a (probably nested) xobject as (AFAIK) PDFBox does not descend into patterns or masks during text extraction.

Comment: That been said, even if there is a font resource associated with a page or its xobjects, there is no guarantee that font is used on the page, so it might be a red herring.

Comment: Thank you for these clues @mkl and @TilmanHausherr! The contents is given by Tika (which may use PDFBox for that under the hood). Actually descending recursively into the `PDFormXObject` did the job. I'll write an answer when it is implemented!

Comment: @HelloWorld Did you ever get this implemented? I have this same issue where getFontNames returns nothing, but I know the PDF has 220 MB of duplicated fonts.